# Why do very large If statements cause a stack overflow

Tags: c++, runtime-error, stack-overflow, sfml

I have coded an if statement spanning a few thousand lines that contains many other nested if statements within. I get a stack overflow error when I don't comment out a lot of it. I know it's due to size because I found that this particular if statement can only handle 6 different blocks of code [the block that says "if (mainmenu1.equipment1A) ] [there are 10 of these per if ((mainmenu1.player1equipment && (Player1.job == 1)) ||... block] and it doesn't matter which blocks are un-commented out if there are 7 no matter which 7 it will give me this following error. It is strange though, This code is part of the code in a game I am working on and the code is in an entirely different gamestate case in a switch statement, and upon startup this code should not be read. I do not receive a compile error when building with none of the code commented out, but upon startup i get this error. Shouln't it be a run time error instead? But in that case, I should not get the error until the program reads the code. I will include a sample of the code, it is about 70,000 lines in all but it is repetitive so imagine this following code times 70.

First-chance exception at 0x103B38B7 (ig7icd32.dll) in SFML.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000000, 0x01072000).
Unhandled exception at 0x103B38B7 (ig7icd32.dll) in SFML.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000000, 0x01072000).

First-chance exception at 0x101AC0BE (ig7icd32.dll) in SFML.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0107091C.
Unhandled exception at 0x101AC0BE (ig7icd32.dll) in SFML.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0107091C.

```
//equipment text
    if (mainmenu1.equipmentmenu2)
    {
        if (executeequipmenttextonce)
        {
            executeequipmenttextonce = false;

            if (mainmenu1.rightselected)
            {
            if ((mainmenu1.player1equipment && (Player1.job == 1)) || (mainmenu1.player2equipment && (Player2.job == 1)) || (mainmenu1.player3equipment && (Player3.job == 1)))
            {
                if (mainmenu1.equipment1A)
                {
                    if (!mainmenu1.knightweapon1displayed && mainmenu1.knightweapon1)
                    {
                        mainmenu1.equipment1A = false;
                        mainmenu1.knightweapon1displayed = true;
                        textDisplay16.text.setString("Broadsword");
                        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(view1.getCenter().x - window.getSize().x / 2 + equipmentPositionX1, view1.getCenter().y - window.getSize().y / 2 + equipmentPositionY1);
                        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);
                        textDisplay16.text.setString(to_string(mainmenu1.knightw1));
                        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(view1.getCenter().x - window.getSize().x / 2 + equipmentPositionX1 + equipmentstockpositionx, view1.getCenter().y - window.getSize().y / 2 + equipmentPositionY1);
                        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);
                    }
                    else if (!mainmenu1.knightweapon2displayed && mainmenu1.knightweapon2)
                    {
                        mainmenu1.equipment1A = false;
                        mainmenu1.knightweapon2displayed = true;
                        textDisplay16.text.setString("Ea");
                        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(view1.getCenter().x - window.getSize().x / 2 + equipmentPositionX1, view1.getCenter().y - window.getSize().y / 2 + equipmentPositionY1);
                        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);
                        textDisplay16.text.setString(to_string(mainmenu1.knightw2));
                        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(view1.getCenter().x - window.getSize().x / 2 + equipmentPositionX1 + equipmentstockpositionx, view1.getCenter().y - window.getSize().y / 2 + equipmentPositionY1);
                        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);
                    }
                    else if (!mainmenu1.knightweapon3displayed && mainmenu1.knightweapon3)
                    {
                        mainmenu1.equipment1A = false;
                        mainmenu1.knightweapon3displayed = true;
                        textDisplay16.text.setString("Zangetsu");
                        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(view1.getCenter().x - window.getSize().x / 2 + equipmentPositionX1, view1.getCenter().y - window.getSize().y / 2 + equipmentPositionY1);
                        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);
                        textDisplay16.text.setString(to_string(mainmenu1.knightw3));
                        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(view1.getCenter().x - window.getSize().x / 2 + equipmentPositionX1 + equipmentstockpositionx, view1.getCenter().y - window.getSize().y / 2 + equipmentPositionY1);
                        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);
                    }
                    else if (!mainmenu1.knightweapon4displayed && mainmenu1.knightweapon4)
                    {
                        mainmenu1.equipment1A = false;
                        mainmenu1.knightweapon4displayed = true;
                        textDisplay16.text.setString("Silver Fleurette");
                        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(view1.getCenter().x - window.getSize().x / 2 + equipmentPositionX1, view1.getCenter().y - window.getSize().y / 2 + equipmentPositionY1);
                        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);
                        textDisplay16.text.setString(to_string(mainmenu1.knightw4));
                        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(view1.getCenter().x - window.getSize().x / 2 + equipmentPositionX1 + equipmentstockpositionx, view1.getCenter().y - window.getSize().y / 2 + equipmentPositionY1);
                        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);
                    }
                    else if (!mainmenu1.knightweapon5displayed && mainmenu1.knightweapon5)
                    {
                        mainmenu1.equipment1A = false;
                        mainmenu1.knightweapon5displayed = true;
                        textDisplay16.text.setString("Lawliet");
                        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(view1.getCenter().x - window.getSize().x / 2 + equipmentPositionX1, view1.getCenter().y - window.getSize().y / 2 + equipmentPositionY1);
                        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);
                        textDisplay16.text.setString(to_string(mainmenu1.knightw5));
                        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(view1.getCenter().x - window.getSize().x / 2 + equipmentPositionX1 + equipmentstockpositionx, view1.getCenter().y - window.getSize().y / 2 + equipmentPositionY1);
                        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);
                    }
                    else if (!mainmenu1.knightweapon6displayed && mainmenu1.knightweapon6)
                    {
                        mainmenu1.equipment1A = false;
                        mainmenu1.knightweapon6displayed = true;
                        textDisplay16.text.setString("Luminous Edge");
                        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(view1.getCenter().x - window.getSize().x / 2 + equipmentPositionX1, view1.getCenter().y - window.getSize().y / 2 + equipmentPositionY1);
                        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);
                        textDisplay16.text.setString(to_string(mainmenu1.knightw6));
                        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(view1.getCenter().x - window.getSize().x / 2 + equipmentPositionX1 + equipmentstockpositionx, view1.getCenter().y - window.getSize().y / 2 + equipmentPositionY1);
                        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);
                    }
                    else if (!mainmenu1.knightweapon7displayed && mainmenu1.knightweapon7)
                    {
                        mainmenu1.equipment1A = false;
                        mainmenu1.knightweapon7displayed = true;
                        textDisplay16.text.setString("Heaven's Saber");
                        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(view1.getCenter().x - window.getSize().x / 2 + equipmentPositionX1, view1.getCenter().y - window.getSize().y / 2 + equipmentPositionY1);
                        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);
                        textDisplay16.text.setString(to_string(mainmenu1.knightw7));
                        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(view1.getCenter().x - window.getSize().x / 2 + equipmentPositionX1 + equipmentstockpositionx, view1.getCenter().y - window.getSize().y / 2 + equipmentPositionY1);
                        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);
                    }
                    else if (!mainmenu1.knightweapon8displayed && mainmenu1.knightweapon8)
                    {
                        mainmenu1.equipment1A = false;
                        mainmenu1.knightweapon8displayed = true;
                        textDisplay16.text.setString("Crystal Edge");
                        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(view1.getCenter().x - window.getSize().x / 2 + equipmentPositionX1, view1.getCenter().y - window.getSize().y / 2 + equipmentPositionY1);
                        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);
                        textDisplay16.text.setString(to_string(mainmenu1.knightw8));
                        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(view1.getCenter().x - window.getSize().x / 2 + equipmentPositionX1 + equipmentstockpositionx, view1.getCenter().y - window.getSize().y / 2 + equipmentPositionY1);
                        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);
                    }
                    else if (!mainmenu1.knightweapon9displayed && mainmenu1.knightweapon9)
                    {
                        mainmenu1.equipment1A = false;
                        mainmenu1.knightweapon9displayed = true;
                        textDisplay16.text.setString("Triple Zoro");
                        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(view1.getCenter().x - window.getSize().x / 2 + equipmentPositionX1, view1.getCenter().y - window.getSize().y / 2 + equipmentPositionY1);
                        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);
                        textDisplay16.text.setString(to_string(mainmenu1.knightw9));
                        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(view1.getCenter().x - window.getSize().x / 2 + equipmentPositionX1 + equipmentstockpositionx, view1.getCenter().y - window.getSize().y / 2 + equipmentPositionY1);
                        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);
                    }
                    else if (!mainmenu1.knightweapon10displayed && mainmenu1.knightweapon10)
                    {
                        mainmenu1.equipment1A = false;
                        mainmenu1.knightweapon10displayed = true;
                        textDisplay16.text.setString("Elsword");
                        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(view1.getCenter().x - window.getSize().x / 2 + equipmentPositionX1, view1.getCenter().y - window.getSize().y / 2 + equipmentPositionY1);
                        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);
                        textDisplay16.text.setString(to_string(mainmenu1.knightw10));
                        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(view1.getCenter().x - window.getSize().x / 2 + equipmentPositionX1 + equipmentstockpositionx, view1.getCenter().y - window.getSize().y / 2 + equipmentPositionY1);
                        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);
                    }
                }
                else if (mainmenu1.equipment2A)
                {
                    if (!mainmenu1.knightweapon1displayed && mainmenu1.knightweapon1)
                    {
                        mainmenu1.equipment2A = false;
                        mainmenu1.knightweapon1displayed = true;
                        textDisplay16.text.setString("Broadsword");
                        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(view1.getCenter().x - window.getSize().x / 2 + equipmentPositionX1, view1.getCenter().y - window.getSize().y / 2 + equipmentPositionY2);
                        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);
                        textDisplay16.text.setString(to_string(mainmenu1.knightw1));
                        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(view1.getCenter().x - window.getSize().x / 2 + equipmentPositionX1 + equipmentstockpositionx, view1.getCenter().y - window.getSize().y / 2 + equipmentPositionY2);
                        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);
                    }
                    else if (!mainmenu1.knightweapon2displayed && mainmenu1.knightweapon2)
                    {
                        mainmenu1.equipment2A = false;
                        mainmenu1.knightweapon2displayed = true;
                        textDisplay16.text.setString("Ea");
                        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(view1.getCenter().x - window.getSize().x / 2 + equipmentPositionX1, view1.getCenter().y - window.getSize().y / 2 + equipmentPositionY2);
                        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);
                        textDisplay16.text.setString(to_string(mainmenu1.knightw2));
                        textDisplay16.text.setPosition(view1.getCenter().x - window.getSize().x / 2 + equipmentPositionX1 + equipmentstockpositionx, view1.getCenter().y - window.getSize().y / 2 + equipmentPositionY2);
                        textDisplayArray16.push_back(textDisplay16);
                    }
                    else if (!mainmenu1.knightweapon3displayed && mainmenu1.knightweapon3)
                    {
                        mainmenu1.equipment2A = false;
                        mainmenu1.knightweapon3displayed = true;
                        textDisplay16.text.setString("Zangetsu");
```

Comment: "I have coded an if statement spanning a few thousand lines"

Comment: ..but look at all those refactorings/design patterns lurking just around the corner, waiting to be discovered!

Comment: Runon sentences and runon code. <g>

Comment: It's crashing inside drawing code so you're feeding it something it doesn't like. It's most likely not really about this code but a side effect. Proper copying of elements in the objects you use?

Comment: "It is about 70,000 lines in all but it is repetitive" - repetitive code is one of the worst of all antipatterns.

Comment: @sami what could be something that causes it to crash upon running the code? it must have something to do with the code i posted here because when I comment the entire thing out it runs perfectly

Comment: You have two exceptions. One is a Stack Overflow and one is Access Violation

Comment: Well, you add things to a vector obviously and judging by the name it is used for drawing something. So this code isn't an isolated block, it causes something to be drawn I assume. If the data is not valid it's easy to crash. You're using static instances, are they copied properly or in a shallow way and pointers dangle?

Comment: You could reduce your code size by changing your design.  One code saver is the use of tables.  Another is `std::vector`, such as `std::vector<Knight>` to contain Knight characters.

Comment: Don't. Do. This. Please.

Comment: @Al Bundy cut the crap allright, without knowing anymore context you cannot possibly tell anything about the OP's talent. Judging people on a single SO question is just as monstrous as the code in question. For all we know he/she just started programming last week, and copy/pasted everything without knowing better. Lots of people started like that you know. And given a couple of years and books/guidance/self-learning they might turn into decent programmers.

Comment: @Al Bundy I'm well aware how terrible the code is and how it can be improved. But again, my point is that does *not* prove anything about the person's possible/future talents. Judging people's abilities based on a single piece of code on the net is just dumb and ignorant, sorry.  Did your very first piece of code adhere to all possible good practices? Can you go back to every piece of code you ever wrote and tell yourself, "this doesn't hurt my eye now and I was being super talented here and if people would judge me by this they'd certainly hire me"? You can't. You understand my point now?

Comment: @WakeUpToFlatEarth may I interest you in http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/component.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Technically, an `if` statement does not consume stack space.

Function calls within an `if` expression may cause a StackOverflow.

Allocating too many local variables in the statement block may cause a stack overflow.

Allocating large variables in the statement block may cause a stack overflow.

Recursive functions that are not limited may cause a stack overflow.

Recursive functions that use a lot of local variables or parameters may cause a stack overflow.

An `if` statement is generally evaluated as a compare instruction and a branch statement.  These instructions don't occupy stack space.

Your errors are probably located elsewhere.

Use a debugger to find the root cause.

Comment: And consider a redesign so you don't need a massive amount of `if` statements. That seems to be OPs biggest problem - huge, unmaintainable and error-prone copy-paste code.

Comment: @WakeUpToFlatEarth Check out http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/component.html . Sorry to double post but the question comment thread is mostly about how bad the code is without a solution offered.